# Having trouble applying DeMorgan's Law?

Tags: boolean-expression, demorgans-law

I'm stumped. I have to apply DeMorgan's Law to the phrase "It is not true that he took both Algebra and CS." and the expression

```
   (X!=Y).(X>Z)
```

but only one of the two in the second problem have a NOT indicator. It can't be !((X=Y).(X>Z)) because there's no NOT indicator in (X>Z). I'm extremely confused, because I was under the impression that in order to use DM's Law, you needed both parts of the expression to have a NOT. Could someone explain this to me?
 For the phrase, my answer was since !(Algebra.CS) = !A + !C, it would be "It is true that he did not take Algebra or CS." Is this correct?

any explanation is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The first expression '**It is NOT TRUE that he took both Algebra AND CS.**' - presuming, that:

```
A ... 'he took Algebra'
C ... 'he took CS'
¬ ... negation, logic not
∧ ... conjunction, logic and
```

would after applying De Morgan's law change this way:

```
¬(A ∧ C) ≍ ¬A ∨ ¬C
```

The equivalent expression is: '**It is NOT TRUE, he took Algebra OR it is NOT TRUE, he took CS.**'

In the second expression you can *substitute* the two coefficients without worrying about their content:

```
A ... (X!=Y)
B ... (X > Z)
¬(¬x) ≍ x ... double negation law

(X!=Y)∧(X > Z) ≍ A ∧ B ≍ ¬(¬A) ∧ ¬(¬B) ≍ ¬(¬A ∨ ¬B) ≍ ¬(¬(X!=Y) ∨ ¬(X > Z))
```

The second expression '**X != Y and X>Y**' is equivalent to '**It is not true, that it is not true X !=Y or that it is not true X>Y**'.

Now it is a matter of interpreting the parenthesis' content. That depends purely on the universe, operands/relations or variables where are you operating. That you did not state in your question.

I can interpret the operand > as arithmetic 'X greater than Y'. Then the negation/complement of it would be (X ≤ Z). If the X is not greater that Y, it is equal or less than it.

In the same manner the not(X!=Y) could be equivalent to (X > Y) ∨ (X < Y). But I am pretty sure, it is no correct '*math talk*' without any additional background or relevant info.

```
¬(¬(X!=Y) ∨ ¬(X > Z)) ≍ ¬(¬((X > Y) ∨ (X < Y)) ∨ ¬(X > Z)) 
                      ≍ ¬((¬(X > Y) ∧ ¬(X < Y)) ∨ (X ≤ Z))
                      ≍ ¬(((X ≤ Y) ∧ (X ≥ Y)) ∨ (X ≤ Z))
```

So '**It is not true, that:**

- **the X is less or equal to Y**
- **and that the X is greater or equal to Y**
- **or that the X is less or equal to Z.**'

And checking based on the previous presumptions:

```
¬(((X ≤ Y) ∧ (X ≥ Y)) ∨ (X ≤ Z)) ≍ ¬((X ≤ Y) ∧  (X ≥ Y)) ∧ ¬(X ≤ Z)
                                 ≍ (¬(X ≤ Y) ∨ ¬(X ≥ Y)) ∧ ¬(X ≤ Z)
                                 ≍  ((X > Y) ∨  (X < Y)) ∧  (X > Z)
                                 ≍              (X != Y) ∧  (X > Z)
```